# How to change XAML file as a template WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates

I have a C# WPF application with 2 templates(group of .xaml files) how can i exclude from project one group of xaml files and include other group without editing project file manually

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, right click the files you want to exclude from the project and click `Exclude from Project`. You can add them back in by doing a right-click on their folder or project and selecting Add --> Existing Item, and then select them in the Open Fire dialog.